# Navigation controller view size to fit [swift]

Tags: swift, uinavigationcontroller

I have this set of code:

```
    MOLPay = MOLPayLib(delegate: self, andPaymentDetails: paymentRequestDict)

    let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: MOLPay)

    let btn: UIButton = UIButton(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 35, 35))
    btn.setImage(UIImage(named: "scan_ic_back.png"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    btn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(MolPayNowViewController.closeMolPay(_:)), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)

    let barButton = UIBarButtonItem(customView: btn)

    MOLPay.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = barButton

    MOLPay.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor(hexString: "#76DD4A")

    self.presentViewController(navigationController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

And it came out become like this, i wanted to show the page size fit to the screen size, but how to do it? Since its a embedded navigation controller. Can someone please help.

[image]

What i want to archieve:

[image]

Comment: Do you want to remove the white space at the top there?

Comment: @Sweeper i just updated my question, please have a look again, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that your `UIWebView` does not resize its contents to make it fit the phone's screen. Am I right?

To make the whole web view's content fit the screen, do this in the view controller:

```
yourWebView.scalesPageToFit = true
```

Comment: i just updated my question, please have a look again, thanks